# quartz running only in even minutes

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler. While I am creating trigger for my job I am setting start time to it by using `trigger.setStartTime()`. Now my problem is in first fire time it runs to nearest even time. Let explain the above case with an example. My Trigger start time is: `Thu Feb 14 13:53:00 IST 2013`. Recurrance cron expression is for every two minutes. So,the first fire time is `Thu Feb 14 13:55:00 IST 2013`. But it is fired at `Thu Feb 14 13:54:00 IST 2013`. From there it runs at every two minutes, i.e `13:56:00,13:58:00` etc.. But I want to fire the job for every two minutes from start time of the trigger. Please help me to achieve that one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share parts of your code. Check TriggerBuilder and .scheduleJob method carefully to make sure you set start time to 13:53:00

Comment: show your code how you are setting startTime to trigger

Comment: thanku for your response.i am using quartz 1.8.my code is as below CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("sample job name","Sample Job Group");   trigger.setStartTime(finalStartingDate); here finalStartingDate returning the start date entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Quartz are you using and how are you building your triggers? If you're using version 2.0 or better, you should probably be using the DSL-like TriggerBuilder and SimpleTrigger/SimpleSchedule to build your triggers quickly and less error prone.

[Quartz Tutorial Lesson 5](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05)

Your trigger would end up lokking something like this:

```
trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("my-trigger", "my-group")
    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
        .withIntervalInMinutes(2)
        .repeatForever())
    .build();
```